# JS Socket.io Disconnect for() loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've got this object

```
obj = { 'Users': [ 'idxx1', 'idxx2', 'idxx3', 'idxx4', 'idxx5', 'idxx6' ], 'Room1': [ 'idxx1', 'idxx2', 'idxx3', 'idxx4', 'idxx5' ] }
```

I can view the contents of `Room1` with:

```
console.log(io.sockets.manager.rooms['Room1']);
```

result:

```
[ 'idxx1', 'idxx2', 'idxx3', 'idxx4', 'idxx5' ]
```

I can get each value separately with a for() loop:

```
for( var key in obj ) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

result:

```
idxx1
idxx2
idxx3
idxx4
idxx5
```

But when I try and disconnect the sockets with:

```
for( var key in obj ) {
  io.sockets.sockets[obj[key]].disconnect();
}
```

(Yes I am using Sockets.io 0.9.16 not v1+ and use the old disconnect method)

It will disconnect every second result eg:

```
idxx1
idxx3
idxx5
```

Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem occurs because `.disconnect()` method removes an element from `obj` array (actually it removes an element from `io.sockets.manager.rooms['Room1']` array, which is reflected on `obj`).

So on the first iteration, `obj` equals to `['idxx1','idxx2','idxx3','idxx4','idxx5']` and `key` equals to `0`, and `idxx1` is removed. It's OK.

But on the second iteration, `obj` equals to `['idxx2','idxx3','idxx4','idxx5']` and `key` is `1` and `obj[1]` equals to `idxx3`. That's why, I think, `idxx2` is skipped. The same goes to `idxx4`.

I see the following solution -- iterate through `obj` in reversed order using `for` loop (not `for-in`):

```
for (var key = obj.length - 1; key >= 0; key--) {
  io.sockets.sockets[obj[key]].disconnect();
}
```

Or use zero index on each `for` iteration:

```
for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
  io.sockets.sockets[obj[0]].disconnect();
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, didn't take into consideration that on disconnect the `idxxx` is deleted. Worked like a charm yet again CuriousGuy!